# Why svn import option fails to detect file duplication

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I want to check-in a file with same name which is already present in SVN, I would not be able to commit in that case. For example: `Name.doc` and `name.doc`. But, I will be able to import in that case.

This case even applicable for folder name. This prevents the operation of check-out in future.

Is there a way to prevent file or folder duplication? or it is not possible in SVN?

Comment: well, I am not sure if you are doing the right thing. `import` is nothing but a combo command for `add` and `commit`. So, you should see the same result in both cases. Also, please remember that Windows is case-insensitive but Unix based OS are not. So, if you are testing the two cases on two different OS, thing are likely to differ.

Answer (score 4):

Subversion is case sensitive. Meaning it is perfectly fine to have multiple items with the same name, e.g. Name.doc, name.doc, NaMe.DOC, ...

TortoiseSVN corrects such filenames automatically in the commit dialog, because there it can check against the working copy BASE and look for files with the same name.
Other SVN clients don't do that, so it's not the commit that prevents this but TortoiseSVN.

However when you do an import, you don't have a working copy against which the filenames can be compared to - and the repository doesn't care. So the import will lead to multiple items with the same name.

If you want to prevent this from happening, you can install a pre-commit hook script on the repository. Subversion provides such a hook script: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/case-insensitive.py

Comment: Thanks a lot stefan... is it possible to prevent such kind of duplications...? bcoz it is prventing the check-out operation....

Comment: oh, thanks a ton for the hook script, my team has run into this before and it was a real pain to resolve.