# How can I configure subversion / TortoiseSVN to handle Windows case-insensitivity nicely?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make Subversion + TortoiseSVN case-insensitive for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582/can-i-make-subversion-tortoisesvn-case-insensitive-for-windows)

There are two files named like this in a folder of our SVN repository:

```
NAME.ext
name.ext
```

TortoiseSVN is (naturally) only able to sync one of these files, not both, due to Windows' case-insensitivity.  Both files need to be kept with those names for our Linux builds to work, and branching isn't really an option.

This is pretty annoying for me since Tortoise constantly shows its red `!` icon on the directory tree; I'd like a visual way of seeing the repo state without needing to do a manual check.  Is there some way to configure Tortoise to ignore the state of files that have the exact same name as another file, apart from case?

I know this is just the way svn is, but it should be simple for Tortoise to ignore what svn's telling it in this case ... assuming Tortoise has that functionality or it can be added in by an end-user.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582/can-i-make-subversion-tortoisesvn-case-insensitive-for-windows) may help.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite. The one answer about turning on case-sensitivity in Windows is pretty interesting, but I'm pretty sure that would break some other stuff we use.

Comment: I would simply rename one of the files, and fix the linux builds. Having two files with the same name, differing only in case, is a recipe for problems and confusion. You've just been hit by the first one.

Comment: @JBNizet Unfortunately it's not up to me, and I suspect it's due to two different external tools using the different casing.

Comment: It's not an oddness with svn, it's an oddness with windows.

Comment: @thekbb No one said anything either way.

Comment: It seems I read into "I know this is just the way svn is..." incorrectly.