# Is it possible to create a case insensitive ignore list in svn?

Tags: svn, version-control, svnignore

I can do this by specifying both cases for each character in each entry:

```
[Bb][Ii][Nn]
*.[Tt][Mm][Pp]
```

Is there a simpler way to turn the whole list case insensitive?

The linked question ([Can I make Subversion + TortoiseSVN case-insensitive for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582/can-i-make-subversion-tortoisesvn-case-insensitive-for-windows)) is similar indeed, but it is about ignoring a case change in a source file name. That is not possible while creating a case insensitive ignore list clearly is (see the above example). It looks like there's no easy way though.

Comment: [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html#tsvn-dug-ignore-glob) has a link to format specs. I think it isn't possible but to be honest the specs are pretty obtuse (as expected).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make Subversion + TortoiseSVN case-insensitive for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582/can-i-make-subversion-tortoisesvn-case-insensitive-for-windows)

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582/can-i-make-subversion-tortoisesvn-case-insensitive-for-windows

Comment: @uzsolt Both links point to the same question. But that question talks about tracking of renamed files, which is a rather different subject.